# Child elements ignore parents width after applying box-direction property

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Fairly simple question, but I can't seem to find a fix for this simple problem. 
I have a list of elements that I need reversed for specific reasons, this needs to be done with CSS only, since the backend generates a normal list.

The box-direction property does this perfectly, only after applying it, the child elements totally ingore the parents width and display next to each other, overflowing out of the parent box.

How can I fix this?

```
<div>
     <p>Cat</p>
     <p>Dog</p>
     <p>Horse</p>
</div>

div {
     width:50px;
     height:100px;
     background-color: red;
     display:-moz-box;
     -moz-box-direction:reverse;
     display:-webkit-box;
     -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
     display:box;
     box-direction:reverse;
 }

p {
     width: 50px;
}
```

example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/KEYqm/2/

Comment: display:box has been deprected kindly move to display:flexbox

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal `display: flexbox` is deprecated in favor of `display: flex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a few things going on here.

First of all, properties from the old Flexbox module should never be used without the modern properties to go with them.  The old specification is incomplete and the Firefox implementation in particular is very poor.

Second of all, Flexbox has quite a few things in common with tables.  By default, flex items are laid out in a row (horizontal) and unless you explicitly say the flex items should wrap, they won't.  You have to make a decision here:  do you want the elements to display vertically or do you want them to be able to wrap?  If you want wrapping, then the number of browsers that can support it is reduced to 3:  Chrome, Opera, IE10.

Assuming you want them displayed vertically, these are the properties you need:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/vomEI

```
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
  -moz-box-direction: reverse;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: And people complain about prefixes on animations, transitions and transforms... :)

Comment: Thankfully, Firefox will be dropping the old properties soon in favor of the prefix free version of the standard properties.